# Creating a Tkinter Button to 'clear' Output

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a very basic program that spits out a string of values, but I am not quite sure how to clear these values.  At the moment I have it set up so that I just exit the window and start a new one so that I'm not rewriting over new values all the time.  Is there a simple way to add another button that just says something like 'clear' and does exactly that?  My code is as below:

```
def create_widgets(self):
        self.entryLabel = Label(self, text="Please enter a list of numbers:")
        self.entryLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)   


    self.listEntry = Entry(self)
    self.listEntry.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)

    self.entryLabel = Label(self, text="Please enter an index value:")
    self.entryLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=E)

    self.indexEntry = Entry(self)
    self.indexEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)

    self.runBttn = Button(self, text="Run Function", command=self.psiFunction)
    self.runBttn.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

    self.answerLabel = Label(self, text="Output List:")
    self.answerLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

    self.clearBttn = Button(self, text="Clear Output", command=)
    self.clearBttn.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

def clear():
    config.self.entryLabel(text="")

    tk.Button(text="write", command=write).grid()
    tk.Button(text="clear", command=clear).grid()

    self.clearBttn = Button(self, text="Clear Output", command=clear)
    self.clearBttn.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Where is the output being sent?  Does it show up in the terminal or in the GUI window?

Comment: It shows up in the GUI through a  self.answerLabel command.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kinda asked two different questions here.  I'll address the first, since that is what you came in with.  To change the label, just update its text using the `config` method:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label()
label.grid()

def write():
    label.config(text="Blah"*6)

def clear():
    label.config(text="")

tk.Button(text="write", command=write).grid()
tk.Button(text="clear", command=clear).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hmm, so all I would need to do is add a new def clear section to the code as you've written?

Comment: Yea, just change the label's text to an empty string to "clear" it.

Comment: I've appended some of the code for the block containing the GUI.  Would something like this work instead to fit it into the way the code is defined now?

Comment: Yea.  Just create a clear function like I did that changes the text of `self.entryLabel` to an empty string (clearing it).  Then, hook a button up to that clear function.  It should work fine.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but would I be able to set it up as above? (edited post)

Comment: You need to stop editing your question.  If you need help on a different subject, ask another question.  However, I will give you some help.  You need to add `self` to this `def clear(self):` and you need to use the `config` method as I showed you `self.entryLabel.config(text="")`.  Finally, you need to use `self.clear` here `self.clearBttn = Button(self, text="Clear Output", command=self.clear)`.

Comment: Thanks again, sorry about the confusion.  I'll get rid of the second question in the post and start fresh with a new post on that one.